# Add prefix to src and css of index.html in react

Tags: reactjs, react-native, webpack, react-router

I am having a react app. At the time of build generation, in my build folder I am getting below code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta name="description" content="Web site created using create-react-app" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/logo192.png" />
    <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json" />
    <title>React App</title>
    <script defer="defer" src="/static/js/main.8d8de8a8.js"></script>
    <link href="/static/css/main.073c9b0a.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body><noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Now, Instead of the URLs starting with `/static` I want them to add a prefix automatically when build is generated such as /test/static in `src` as well as `href` tag. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try running npm run eject, this will generate webpack config files there you will find that parameter and you can change it.

Answer (score 1):

To configure the react build, do the following:

**run:** `npm run eject` or `yarn eject`

The repository has to be at the latest commit, otherwise the command will not generate the configuration files. The command will generate configuration files for create-react-app.

Once you see that the files are generated, look for the following file:

```
 config/webpack.config.js
```

With your text editor look for something like `static/` you will see that it is the path configured for the static files. You can replace it with a route of your choice.

**Warning:** A configuration error in this file may cause your project not to compile or the development server not to start.

Comment: This is doing the job but when deployed on a nginx server and hitting URL it is still hitting IP/static/* and what I want is IP/test/static. Do you have any idea on how to fix this?